# How to fix the bug in Command Prompt: 'auto-py-to-exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: python, windows, exe, command-prompt, auto-py-to-exe

how to fix:

```
'auto-py-to-exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I checked and I add the proper path to Environmental Variables:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.2364]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

U:\>set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\Scripts

U:\>pip install auto-py-to-exe
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Looking in indexes: https://anu9rng:****@rb-artifactory.bosch.com/artifactory/api/pypi/python-virtual/simple
Requirement already satisfied: auto-py-to-exe in c:\users\stj2tw\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (2.26.1)
Requirement already satisfied: Eel==0.14.0 in c:\users\stj2tw\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from auto-py-to-exe) (0.14.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyinstaller>=4.6 in c:\users\stj2tw\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from auto-py-to-exe) (5.7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: future in c:\program files\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from Eel==0.14.0->auto-py-to-exe) (0.18.2)
Requirement already satisfied: bottle in c:\users\stj2tw\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from Eel==0.14.0->auto-py-to-exe) (0.12.23)
Requirement already satisfied: whichcraft in c:\program files\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from Eel==0.14.0->auto-py-to-exe) (0.6.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing in c:\program files\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from Eel==0.14.0->auto-py-to-exe) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: bottle-websocket in c:\users\stj2tw\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from Eel==0.14.0->auto-py-to-exe) (0.2.9)
Requirement already satisfied: pywin32-ctypes>=0.2.0 in c:\program files\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pyinstaller>=4.6->auto-py-to-exe) (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pefile>=2022.5.30 in c:\users\stj2tw\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from pyinstaller>=4.6->auto-py-to-exe) (2022.5.30)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=42.0.0 in c:\program files\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pyinstaller>=4.6->auto-py-to-exe) (58.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: pyinstaller-hooks-contrib>=2021.4 in c:\users\stj2tw\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from pyinstaller>=4.6->auto-py-to-exe) (2022.15)
Requirement already satisfied: altgraph in c:\users\stj2tw\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from pyinstaller>=4.6->auto-py-to-exe) (0.17.3)
Requirement already satisfied: gevent-websocket in c:\users\stj2tw\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from bottle-websocket->Eel==0.14.0->auto-py-to-exe) (0.10.1)
Requirement already satisfied: gevent in c:\program files\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from gevent-websocket->bottle-websocket->Eel==0.14.0->auto-py-to-exe) (21.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.12.2 in c:\program files\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from gevent->gevent-websocket->bottle-websocket->Eel==0.14.0->auto-py-to-exe) (1.14.6)
Requirement already satisfied: zope.event in c:\program files\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from gevent->gevent-websocket->bottle-websocket->Eel==0.14.0->auto-py-to-exe) (4.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: greenlet<2.0,>=1.1.0 in c:\program files\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from gevent->gevent-websocket->bottle-websocket->Eel==0.14.0->auto-py-to-exe) (1.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: zope.interface in c:\program files\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from gevent->gevent-websocket->bottle-websocket->Eel==0.14.0->auto-py-to-exe) (5.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in c:\program files\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from cffi>=1.12.2->gevent->gevent-websocket->bottle-websocket->Eel==0.14.0->auto-py-to-exe) (2.20)

U:\>auto-py-to-exe
'auto-py-to-exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

```
U:\>echo %PATH%
C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\RedHat\java-1.8.0-openjdk\missioncontrol\;C:\Program Files\RedHat\java-1.8.0-openjdk\webstart\;C:\Program Files\RedHat\java-1.8.0-openjdk\bin;C:\Program Files\RedHat\java-1.8.0-openjdk\jre\bin;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\7-Zip;C:\Program Files (x86)\Plantronics\Spokes3G\;C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\condabin;C:\Program Files (x86)\RedHat\java-1.8.0-openjdk\webstart\;C:\Program Files (x86)\RedHat\java-1.8.0-openjdk\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\RedHat\java-1.8.0-openjdk\jre\bin;C:\Program Files\Siemens\Teamcenter14.1\Visualization\Products\Mockup\ClearanceDB;C:\Users\STJ2TW\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\Scripts
```

I also tried:

```
U:\>python -m pip install auto-py-to-exe

U:\>python -m auto_py_to_exe

U:\>pip show --files auto-py-to-exe
Name: auto-py-to-exe
Version: 2.26.1
Summary: Converts .py to .exe using a simple graphical interface.
Home-page: https://github.com/brentvollebregt/auto-py-to-exe
Author: Brent Vollebregt
Author-email: brent@nitratine.net
License: MIT
Location: c:\users\stj2tw\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages
Requires: pyinstaller, Eel
Required-by:
Files:
  ..\Scripts\auto-py-to-exe.exe
  ..\Scripts\autopytoexe.exe
  auto_py_to_exe-2.26.1.dist-info\INSTALLER
  auto_py_to_exe-2.26.1.dist-info\LICENSE
  auto_py_to_exe-2.26.1.dist-info\METADATA
  auto_py_to_exe-2.26.1.dist-info\RECORD
  auto_py_to_exe-2.26.1.dist-info\REQUESTED
  auto_py_to_exe-2.26.1.dist-info\WHEEL
  auto_py_to_exe-2.26.1.dist-info\entry_points.txt
  auto_py_to_exe-2.26.1.dist-info\top_level.txt
  auto_py_to_exe\__init__.py
  auto_py_to_exe\__main__.py
  auto_py_to_exe\__pycache__\__init__.cpython-39.pyc
  auto_py_to_exe\__pycache__\__main__.cpython-39.pyc
  auto_py_to_exe\__pycache__\config.cpython-39.pyc
  auto_py_to_exe\__pycache__\dialogs.cpython-39.pyc
  auto_py_to_exe\__pycache__\packaging.cpython-39.pyc
  auto_py_to_exe\__pycache__\ui.cpython-39.pyc
  auto_py_to_exe\__pycache__\utils.cpython-39.pyc
  auto_py_to_exe\__pycache__\validation.cpython-39.pyc
  auto_py_to_exe\config.py
  auto_py_to_exe\dialogs.py
  auto_py_to_exe\packaging.py
  auto_py_to_exe\ui.py
  auto_py_to_exe\utils.py
  auto_py_to_exe\validation.py
  auto_py_to_exe\web\Nunito-Light.ttf
  auto_py_to_exe\web\css\general.css
  auto_py_to_exe\web\css\main.css
  auto_py_to_exe\web\css\modal.css
  auto_py_to_exe\web\favicon.ico
  auto_py_to_exe\web\img\chevron-square-up.svg
  auto_py_to_exe\web\img\plus.svg
  auto_py_to_exe\web\img\remove.svg
  auto_py_to_exe\web\index.html
  auto_py_to_exe\web\js\configuration.js
  auto_py_to_exe\web\js\constants.js
  auto_py_to_exe\web\js\i18n.js
  auto_py_to_exe\web\js\importExport.js
  auto_py_to_exe\web\js\initialise.js
  auto_py_to_exe\web\js\interface.js
  auto_py_to_exe\web\js\messages.js
  auto_py_to_exe\web\js\modal.js
  auto_py_to_exe\web\js\packaging.js
  auto_py_to_exe\web\js\staticEvents.js
  auto_py_to_exe\web\js\utils.js

U:\>auto-py-to-exe
'auto-py-to-exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

U:\>C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\Scripts\auto-py-to-exe.exe
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

U:\>auto-py-to-exe.exe
'auto-py-to-exe.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

U:\>auto-py-to-exe.exe
'auto-py-to-exe.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

U:\>autopytoexe.exe
'autopytoexe.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

U:\>autopytoexe
'autopytoexe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

U:\>python -m auto_py_to_exe
```

And nothing happened.

When I try to start the program:

```
U:\>start auto-py-to-exe
The system cannot find the file auto-py-to-exe.
```

It seems like this file doesn't exist.

I would be grateful for any help.
It's computer from work so I don't have any admin's rights and access.

Comment: It's clearly in `..\Scripts\auto-py-to-exe.exe`; make sure you add this directory to your `PATH` (I'm guessing that means `c:\users\stj2tw\appdata\roaming\python\python39\Scripts`?)

Comment: Yes, it worked. Before I add "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\Scripts" but it seems it wasn't enough. Thank you!